# Really nice sound!

Tags: commercials, creative-inspiration

I am currently working on a project for an advertising agency that will require super nice accessible sound design, Its a bit out of my comfort zone (i like it evil (muh hu hu hu ha)).

So my question to you guys is about adverts, what are your favorite sounding adverts?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2JWIcgu7Ag

[youtube]i2JWIcgu7Ag[/youtube]

I love this one, the sound throughout is beautiful and of course the hang drum at the end is lovely.

Answer (score 2):

I rarely listen to ads (thats what the mute button is for) but I love the beautiful attention to detail & characterful sounds for this Honda ad (605 takes apparently)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEF0cg1j35o

Comment: Oh yeah, that add is beautiful.  I wonder how much of the sound is real and how much is foley...

Comment: I have always loved that ad!

Answer (score 1):

Canal Plus in France has recently been promoting a new series called Carlos. The advert was very well produced in terms of sound design! I'm not sure exactly which agency did the sound but the ad agency was the giant, Euro RSCG, so they obviously had a fairly decent budget!

http://series-tv.premiere.fr/News-video/VIDEO-Carlos-la-promo-explosive/(gid)/2314489

Whilst searching for the video I came across another very well made ad by Canal Plus that's great in terms of sound design and very funny at the same time! The clip is from youtube so it's out of sync and very compressed, but you get the idea...enjoy!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZTILiCksP4

Answer (score 0):

My favorite sounding advert is whichever one I'm mixing at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a hangdrum in the nurofen commercial, who would have thought that instrument would end up in a pharmaceutical commercial ;)

I really like this commercial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQ3D4CqHbJM

More Slow-motion sound design, just like the canal plus example, not too present and nicely balanced with the music.(maybe too many wooshes after a second listen tho)